# Continuity and Rational/Irrational Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, irrational-numbers

Does anyone have a proof for this? Consider the function:

$f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $

defined by:

$f(x) = 0$ if $x\notin \mathbb Q$

$f(x) = 1/n$ if $x\in \mathbb Q $\ {$0$}

$f(x) = 0$ if $x=0$

Prove that f is continuous at ever irrational number and discontinuous at every rational number.

Comment: Depends on how you define $n$.

Comment: see Dirichlet function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae's_function

Comment: Did you mean 1/n or 1/x?

Comment: It is $1/q$ for $x=p/q$, where $gcd(p,q)=1$.